# kibana logstash table row color based on log level

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

This seems all too simple but I haven't been able to find anything on the internet about it.

I'm setting up Kibana to visualise our logs (log4j). I would like WARN and ERROR (loglevel field in ElasticSearch) to be in another colour in the table view of entries returned from a query. Is this possible?

Thanks, 
Steve

Comment: Nobody? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no.  You'd need to modify the kibana source code to accomplish something like that.

Comment: Right now it is impossible. But take a look at https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created simple, dirty patch for kibana-3.1.1. 
Text color becomes red when JSON data has "level" field and its value is "error"

Patch:
`https://github.com/mamewotoko/kibana/commit/b96078a950f26d1036f747fc73091e5577a8d9eb`

Sample data:

```
{"index":{"_index":"xxxlog","_type":"log","_id":0}}
{ "level": "error", "message": "Error!!" }
```